# intellij and ResourceBundle

Tags: intellij-idea, resourcebundle

I try to run tests from Intellij. Methods I test uses some properties files from src/main/resources but seems like they are ignored when I run it as JUnit test. It works when I run it from eclipse and ant but not from Intellij. How can I make my src/main/resources visible for tests in Intellij? Dont know if it matters but test and main folders are treated like separated modules in my project view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verify that **src/main/resources** is set as **Sources** or as **Test Sources** in the [project structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html). Resources from such folders are copied to the output path (classpath) automatically according to `Settings | Compiler | Resource Patterns`.